# Is there a way to detect if a Window has been flashed?

Tags: windows, winapi, win32gui

Using functions [FlashWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-flashwindow) and [FlashWindowEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-flashwindowex), one can cause a window to flash.  However, I can't seem to find any API that would detect if a window has been flashed.  Does one exist?

## Edit

Given that [FLASHWINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-flashwinfo) has `DWORD dwFlags`, I would have guessed that this info would be stored in the window and would be accessible using either [GetWindowLongW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowlongw) or [GetWindowLongPtrW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowlongptrw), but I can't find it there.

Reason I need this is for automation.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [`ShellProc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644991(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

> lParam [in]
> Type: **LPARAM**
> **HSHELL_REDRAW** The value is **TRUE** if the window is flashing, or **FALSE** otherwise.

So we just need to add a [`SetWindowsHookExA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa?redirectedfrom=MSDN) function to catch the `WH_SHELL` message.

Here is a sample:

```
#include <Windows.h>
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
LRESULT CALLBACK procShell(int, WPARAM, LPARAM);
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    HHOOK hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_SHELL, procShell, NULL,GetCurrentThreadId());
    int e = GetLastError();
    static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT("Test Flashing");
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASS wndclass;
    wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;
    if (!RegisterClass(&wndclass))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("This program requires Windows NT!"), szAppName, MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindow(szAppName,
        szAppName,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    while (GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
    }
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook);
    return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        FlashWindow(hwnd, TRUE);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
LRESULT CALLBACK procShell(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (nCode == HSHELL_REDRAW) {
        if (lParam)
        {
            OutputDebugString(L"Window is flashing\n");
        }
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

If  we press the left button, the [`FlashWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-flashwindow) will be called. Then the hook function will get the HSHELL_REDRAW message and output:

[image]

Comment: Hi,if this answer did help to you, please feel free to mark it to help people with the same issue, and let me know if you have any problem.Thanks.

Comment: I meet a same problem, but the flashing window belongs to an instant messenger application without code open. The FlashWindow/FlashWindowEx API does not work in RDP RemoteApp context. I need to run my process to monitor that messenger process's window flash.

Comment: @Acewind You can post a question so that the community can understand your question in detail.